# R shiny : use an input in a model

Tags: r, shiny

In the below toy example I fit a model. Then I try to use it to do prediction. My issue is that while the model fits well using the variable `input$group`, the prediction function that uses this same model does not recognize this input.

> Error message : Warning: Error in get: 'input' object not found

```
library(shiny)
library(frailtypack)
data("readmission", package = "frailtypack")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("prediction"),

  sidebarPanel(


wellPanel(
    selectInput("time",
      label = h5("Time :"),
      choices = names(readmission)),

    selectInput("cens_ind",
      label = h5("Censoring indicator :"),
      choices = names(readmission)),

      selectInput("group",
        label = h5("Cluster :"),
        choices = names(readmission)),


    selectizeInput("co_var",
      label = h5("Co-variables :"),
      choices = names(readmission),
      multiple = TRUE)),


    actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("print"),
    plotOutput("pred")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

datapred <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
  DF = subset(readmission[0,],select = c(input$time,input$cens_ind,input$group,input$co_var))
  DF
})


model <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
  frailtyPenal(as.formula(paste("Surv(get(input$time),get(input$cens_ind))~cluster(get(input$group)) +", paste(input$co_var, collapse = " + "))),
  data=readmission,n.knots=10,kappa=10000)
})

predict <- reactive({
    datapred <- datapred()

     prediction(model(),datapred,t=100,window=seq(50,1900,50))

})
output$print <- renderPrint({
  print(model())
})

output$pred <- renderPlot({
    predict <- predict()
    if (!is.null(predict)) plot(predict)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To test the code select settings as follow :Time -> time, Censor indicator -> event, Cluster -> id and co-variable -> dukes.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the library(rlang) and use the following replacement in your subset function:

```
!!rlang::sym(input$group)
```

Comment: I tried but it still does not work. Now I have the following error message : Warning: Error in [: type 'list' of incorrect index